# Persistent module loading not working

Tags: rhel, kernel-modules

Red Hat 6

2.6.32-754.el6.x86_64

I've been working away on two drivers, one is a DMA driver that talks to a PCIe FPGA card. The other, a network driver. The network driver has a dependency on the DMA driver. I have manually added the modules using modprobe and it works as expected. lsmod shows the dependency as expected:

```
modprobe xgbeth
[root@axh-dt sysadmin]# lsmod | grep xgbeth
xgbeth                 33963  0
xdma                  171879  1 xgbeth
```

I'm now trying to get these modules to load at boot. I followed this guide:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-persistent_module_loading

I ended up with a .modules file in /etc/sysconfig/modules/ with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /sbin/modprobe xgbeth
```

Now, on a reboot. I can see the xdma driver being loaded (and can see it in lsmod), but the xgbeth driver isn't being loaded. I have to manually load it using modprobe.

I can't see any messages that indicate anything going wrong in /var/log/messages

Can anybody shed any light as to where this might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you change something about the kernel (include kernel modules), it's always a good idea to update the initrd.

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-6-how-to-rebuild-initial-ramdisk-image/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried it but unfortunately still no joy getting the xgbeth module loaded on boot.